# Send object in JSP as foreign key using Spring MVC and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to create a bank account register related to a specific Person in a OneToMany relationship.

I have the clas Pessoa (Person):

```
@Entity
public class Pessoa {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idPessoa;
    private String nome;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pessoa", targetEntity = ContaCorretora.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ContaCorretora> contaCorretora;
```

...and the class ContaCorretora (Bank account):

```
@Entity
public class ContaCorretora {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int idConta;
    private TipoConta tipoConta;
    private TipoRisco tipoRisco;
    private String login;
    private String senha;
    private BigDecimal valorAtual;
     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="idPessoa")
     private Pessoa pessoa;
```

I'm using this method in Controller for start the process of registration:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "pessoacorretora/{id}") 
public ModelAndView pessoaCorretora(@PathVariable("id") int id, ContaCorretora contaCorretora ) {
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Pessoa pessoa = pessoaDao.find(id);     
    model.put("pessoa", pessoa);
    model.put("tipoConta", TipoConta.values());
    model.put("tipoRisco", TipoRisco.values());
    return new ModelAndView("corretora/contacorretora", "model", model);        
}
```

Sumarizining, I have a specific page for recording bank accounts. So, I created this form:

```
<form:form action="${s:mvcUrl('CC#gravar').build() }" method="post" commandName="contaCorretora" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

    <div class="form-group" >
        <label>Conta</label>
        <select name="tipoConta">
            <c:forEach items="${model.tipoConta}" var="tipoConta">
                  <option value=${tipoConta}>${tipoConta}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" >
        <label>Risco</label>
        <select name="tipoRisco">
            <c:forEach items="${model.tipoRisco}" var="tipoRisco">
                  <option value=${tipoRisco}>${tipoRisco}</option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </div>

            <div class="form-group">
        <label>Login</label>
        <form:input path="login" cssClass="form-control" /> 

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Senha</label>
        <form:input path="senha" cssClass="form-control" /> 

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Valor Atual</label>
        <form:input path="valorAtual" cssClass="form-control" /> 

    </div>  
    <form:hidden path="pessoa" cssClass="form-control" value="${pessoa}"/> 

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Cadastrar</button>
</form:form>
```

When I use the form in this way, I receive the error "description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect." I figured out that the problem is in this line, because when I delete, the form post ok:

```
<form:hidden path="pessoa" cssClass="form-control" value="${pessoa}"/>
```

Nevertheless, if I delete this line, the program doesn't save the idPessoa as a foreign key, this field is null. I would like to know how to pass an entire object in my JSP form. The post method is:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView gravar(ContaCorretora contaCorretora)   {       
    contaCorretoraDao.gravar(contaCorretora);
    return new ModelAndView("pessoa/listageral"); 
}
```

all the DAO's methods are okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to send the primary key of pessoa to the form.
Change the form attribute

```
<form:hidden path="pessoa.idPessoa" cssClass="form-control" value="${model.pessoa.idPessoa}"/>
```

Before persisting the `ContaCorretora`, make sure you get the Pessoa object from db.

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView gravar(ContaCorretora contaCorretora)   { 

    contaCorretora.setPessoa(pessoaDao.find(contaCorretora.getPessoa().getIdPessoa()));
    //I escaped  null check and not found exceptions, you should apply some logic to take care of that
    contaCorretoraDao.gravar(contaCorretora);
    return new ModelAndView("pessoa/listageral"); 
}
```

Using Entities as form model is not a good approach. Persistance layer should not be on the MVC layer.

Comment: Sorry i don't understand well your answer. I used these commands in my method POST request, but the form continues with error.

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida sorry, I added the from hidden attribute as plain text so it was really hidden in my answer , I added it again please read my edit

Comment: Now I understand your point. I used exactly how your show me and it works!. I only had to change the value="${pessoa.idPessoa} to value="${model.pessoa.idPessoa}

Comment: @MuriloGóesdeAlmeida great can you mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass Java object from your Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView gravar(ContaCorretora contaCorretora)   {       
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("pessoa/listageral");
    // retrieve object from DAO
    Object myObj = Dao.find(id);
    // Put object into model map
    mav.addObject("myObj", myObj);
    // return model and view
    return mav;
}
```

In JSP you can refer to object using [ExpressionLanguage syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

```
  ${myObj}
```